# How to remove the margins of child that parent contains some padding?

Tags: html, css

Let's say i have,

```
<div style="padding: 15px; width: 100%;">
   <div style="margin: -15px;; width: 100%;">
       <img src="http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/51/tigerso.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
   </div>
</div>
```

The parent div contains 15px padding and - child div wanted to remove this padding by using margin but it does not work. See this fiddle. It's showing me a horizontal scrollbar always.
http://jsfiddle.net/2GJnG/

Comment: remove width 100% from your DIV

Comment: What restrictions/control do you have?

Comment: if you want, you should define px rather than percantage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `width` properties of the two `div` elements:

```
<div style="padding: 15px;">
    <div style="margin: -15px;">
        <img src="http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/51/tigerso.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

See a demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/2GJnG/5/